# proof by induction for summation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

This is not a duplicate.  I know my conjecture is right, just need to prove it, using induction(not Gauss Method).
Conjecture formula from following equations, and prove conjecture:
$1=1,\\2+3+4=1+8,\\5+6+7+8+9=8+27,\\10+11+12+13+14+15+16=27+64\\$

$S(n)=\sum_{i=(n-1)^2+1}^{n^2}i=(n-1)^3+n^3$

$S(1)=1=1\\S(2)=2+3+4=1+8\\S(3)=5+6+7+8+9=8+27\\S(4)=10+11+12+13+14+15+16=27+64$

Need to show $S(n+1)=\sum_{i=n^2+1}^{(n+1)^2}i=n^3+(n+1)^3$

It's kind of hairy with the variable in the summation.  Seems like there should be a simpler way to prove it than trying to work out that summation.

Assume $S(n)$ true.  So $S(n+1)=(n-1)^3+n^3+?$

Thanks.

Yes, I am aware that $\sum_{i=k}^ni=\sum_{i=1}^ni-\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}i$ and that $\sum_{i=1}^ni = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ and that can be used.

Comment: Can you use a formula for $\sum_{i=1}^n i$? You could prove that by induction then use it here.

Comment: Since none of the terms of $S(n)$ appear in $S(n+1),$ induction on $n$ in $S(n)$ seems a bit of a stretch. You could observe that each of the first $2n-1$ terms of $S(n+1)$ is just $2n-1$ greater than the corresponding term of $S(n),$ and then add $2(n+1)^2-1$ more for the last two terms, totaling $6n^2+2,$ but the part where you sum the differences of the first $2n-1$ terms is much more like a Gauss trick then a proper induction.

Comment: @JonasMeyer: I thought about that but it throws me off as it does not start from 1.

Comment: @user2008730: $5+6+7+8+9 = (1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9)-(1+2+3+4)$.

Comment: @JonasMeyer: Yeah I thought about that but was just wondering if there was another way.

Comment: @user2008730: It isn't clear in your question.  What is wrong with this way?

Comment: @JonasMeyer: THere's nothing wrong with doing it that way it's just that when I tried to I ended up making arithmetic errors.  It's just a big simplification.  I might post the solution later.  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Use $S(n+1)=\sum_{i=1}^{(n+1)^2}i-(n-1)^3+(n)^3$